# Como puedo sumar los valores que me arroja un contador en python?

Tags: python

Tengo una variable func_b que viene desde dos bucles for, estos me dan 16 iteraciones que al final muestran valores de 0 o 1, como podria contar todos los valores que me arroje la variable func_b?

El codigo genera dos numeros random para una posicion y un angulo, estos a su vez cumplen una condicion en la que si no se encuentran en el rango de angulo especificado la variable func_b es 0, caso contrario es 1.

```
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.random import uniform as unif
    from math import sqrt
    from math import asin
    from math import atan
    a=0 ; b=5 
    c=0 ; d=np.pi/2 
    p1=[5,5] 
    p2=[10,5] 
    p3=[7,10] 
    p4=[15,10] 
    L= sqrt(((p2[0]-p1[0])**2)+((p2[1]-p1[1])**2)) 
    tethac=0 
    y= p1[1] 
    N= 4 
    Rx=np.zeros(N) 
    Rtetha=np.zeros(N)
    x=0
    tetha=0
    for i in range (len(Rx)): 
        Rx[i]=unif(0,1) 
        for j in range (len(Rtetha)):
            Rtetha[j]=unif(0,1) 
            x=L*sqrt(Rx[i]) 
            tetha= asin(sqrt(Rtetha[i])) 
            pr=[x,y] 
            m1=(p4[1]-pr[1])/(p4[0]-pr[0]) 
            m2=(p3[1]-pr[1])/(p3[0]-pr[0]) 
            tetha1= atan(m1) 
            tetha2= atan(m2) 
            if m2 < 0:
                tetha2 = np.pi + atan(m2)
            if tetha >= 0 and tetha <= np.pi/2:
                tethac=(np.pi/2)-tetha
            if tetha > np.pi/2 and tetha <= np.pi:
                tethac=(np.pi/2)+tetha
            func_b=0 
            if tethac >= tetha1 and tethac <= tetha2:
                func_b=1 
            print(func_b)
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Por cierto, en tu código no hay ninguna función, ¿Te refieres a la variable `func_b`?

Comment: Si, perdon, me refiero a contar los valores que me arroja la variable func_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, el problema que tienes es que inicializas tu variable `func_b` adentro del ciclo `for` por lo que en cada iteración se hace `0` y luego adentro del `if` se hace `1`.

Lo que debes hacer es inicializar tu variable antes de los ciclos `for` e incrementar el valor de `func_b` cada vez que entre al `if`

Para incrementar el valor puedes utilizar

```
func_b = func_b + 1
```

O utilizar el operador `+=` que equivale a lo mismo

```
func_b += 1
```

Por último, imprimir el valor de `func_b` debería ser después de los ciclos `for` para que te imprima el resultado después de la ejecución

Ejemplo completo:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import uniform as unif
from math import sqrt
from math import asin
from math import atan
a=0 ; b=5 
c=0 ; d=np.pi/2 
p1=[5,5] 
p2=[10,5] 
p3=[7,10] 
p4=[15,10] 
L= sqrt(((p2[0]-p1[0])**2)+((p2[1]-p1[1])**2)) 
tethac=0 
y= p1[1] 
N= 4 
Rx=np.zeros(N) 
Rtetha=np.zeros(N)
x=0
tetha=0
# Inicializar la variable func_b
func_b=0

for i in range (len(Rx)): 
    Rx[i]=unif(0,1) 
    for j in range (len(Rtetha)):
        Rtetha[j]=unif(0,1) 
        x=L*sqrt(Rx[i]) 
        tetha= asin(sqrt(Rtetha[i])) 
        pr=[x,y] 
        m1=(p4[1]-pr[1])/(p4[0]-pr[0]) 
        m2=(p3[1]-pr[1])/(p3[0]-pr[0]) 
        tetha1= atan(m1) 
        tetha2= atan(m2) 
        if m2 < 0:
            tetha2 = np.pi + atan(m2)
        if tetha >= 0 and tetha <= np.pi/2:
            tethac=(np.pi/2)-tetha
        if tetha > np.pi/2 and tetha <= np.pi:
            tethac=(np.pi/2)+tetha
         
        if tethac >= tetha1 and tethac <= tetha2:
            # Incrementar la variable func_b
            func_b+=1

# Imprimir el valor después de los ciclos for
print(func_b)
```

El resultado varía según los números generados aleatoriamente por lo que puedes comprobar su funcionamiento al ejecutar el código.